# Changes which are not yet merged to remote

Tags: git, gerrit

Merge commit is a collection of commits [it includes multiple commits]. i am running below command to check the changes which are not part of remote branch i.e. changes which are not merged yet to remote branch :

```
   git rev-list local_branch  --not origin/remote_branch --no-merges
```

But it is not showing me the commit id of merge commit, instead its showing me all the changes which are included in that commit.

So lets say i have commit 'A' which is a combination of commit 'B' ,  'C' and 'D'. I pulled change 'A' to my local repo and ran below command :

```
   git rev-list local_branch  --not origin/remote_branch --no-merges
```

it is showing me commit IDs of 'B' , 'C' and 'D' only. Is there any way i can see the commit ID of merge commit which is not yet merged into remote branch??

Answer (score 2):

You can just use :

```
git log <commit_id> -1 --pretty="%p"
```

For simple commit it will show you only one parent for merge commit there will be two or more than two parents.